# Count multiple characters php

Tags: php, mysql, count

I'm trying to use `strlen` or something like that to count multiple set of characters
in a string.
Here's the database string

```
xa1xb2xcxd3xe4xcxa5xb6xcxd7xe8xcxa9xb10xcxd11xe12xcxa13xb14xc
```

I get the string from the database and i want to count the number of

"xa" "xb" "xd" and "xe" that the string contains.

I Guess i could count first xa then xb then xd then xe with `strlen` and then adding the numbers but isn't there an easier way?

Please help!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you open to `preg_match_all` solution?

```
echo preg_match_all('/x(a|b|d|e)/', $message, $matches)
```

From the [docs](http://php.net/preg_match_all):

> Returns the **number of full pattern matches** (which might be zero), or
>   FALSE if an error occurred.

Although this returns the *aggregated* number of `xa,xb,xd and xe`, not the individual ones

If you need to get individual ones, you need one more step with `array_count_values`:

```
$sums = array_count_values($matches[0]);
print_r($sums);
```

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa yeah... I'll think of another solution that isn't already mentioned below. Thanks!

Comment: @user1430587 Edited my answer to also get individual ones :)

Comment: What is $matches for?
I use $totalteknisk = preg_match_all('/x(a|b|d|e)/', $description2, $matches); But Matches?

Comment: It's an array where php will then put all the matches. You can try doing `var_dump($matches)` to see what it contains

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
$string ="xa1xb2xcxd3xe4xcxa5xb6xcxd7xe8xcxa9xb10xcxd11xe12xcxa13xb14xc";

echo substr_count($string, 'xa')."<br>";
echo substr_count($string, 'xb')."<br>";
echo substr_count($string, 'xc')."<br>";
echo substr_count($string, 'xd')."<br>";
```

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa this one has `xc` considered :p

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

```
$text = "xa1xb2xcxd3xe4xcxa5xb6xcxd7xe8xcxa9xb10xcxd11xe12xcxa13xb14xc";
echo substr_count($text, 'xa');
echo substr_count($text, 'xb');
echo substr_count($text, 'xd');
```